# Why is this the simple past despite the previous sentence with past perfect tense?

Tags: grammar, tense

> The United States surpassed 700,000 deaths from the coronavirus on Friday, a milestone that few experts had anticipated months ago when vaccines became widely available to the American public.[NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/10/01/us/us-covid-deaths-700k.html?referringSource=articleShare)

Here, at first, I thought it meant “the experts did not anticipate this bad situation because vaccines will be widely available in the future”.
But my friends said it meant “when vaccines became widely available, the experts did not anticipate the high death toll.”

I’m confuses here. If the anticipation occurred at the same time when the vaccines became widely available, why is the anticipation the past perfect and why is the wh-clause just the simple past tense?

The anticipation is the past perfect tense, and the wh-clause is the simple past tense, so I guess the time order is “1. the experts had not expected the high death toll at first, and then 2. the vaccines became widely available later.”, since the time order is the past perfect tense occurs first and then the simple past occurs.

But if so, it does not make sense if the original sentence means “when the vaccines became widely available, the experts did not expect at the same time”.

Why is the wh-clause the simple past tense here if it occurred at the same time as the anticipation?
Please help me.

Comment: Do you know the function of the past perfect? How is it different in this sentence to what you expected?

Comment: @gotube Yeah, cuz the past perfect is used to talk about the actions before some point in the past, I’m not sure why the When clause is the simple past. If when clause is the reason of the anticipated clause, why is when clause the simple past?

Comment: I agree with Mango Gummy. The word "had" could safely be deleted. If they were saying "...a milestone that few experts had anticipated months ago, BEFORE vaccines became widely available..." it would be grammatically correct, though the meaning of the whole sentence would be messed up.